# GUI Designer for Ruby

Tags: ruby, user-interface, ide

I have been looking for this for a long time.

Is there a rapid application development tool for GUI design using Ruby? I don't care if it is Windows or Linux, and not even which graphics toolkit. As long as it works, anything goes. I am ready to learn if need be.

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of ruby projects are you interested in making?  A website?  A stand alone application?

Comment: I am looking forward to building standalone applications.. No Rails for a while :)

Comment: What is your target platform?  Windows? Mac? Linux? Android?

Comment: Cross-platform, but mainly for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 4):

What about Ruby Shoes?

http://shoesrb.com/

Comment: You didn't actually ask for an IDE. Are you looking for a drag and drop GUI designer or a Ruby GUI toolkit?

Comment: Please forgive my poor English... Yes, I am looking for a drag&drop GUI designer, with perhaps an editor built-in too.

Comment: http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Tutorials/Ruby-In-Steel-Tutorials/GUI-Drag-and-Drop-Development-For

Answer (score 2):

Glade, A User Interface Designer.

it works for GTK+.

> Glade is a RAD tool to enable quick & easy development of user interfaces for the GTK+ toolkit and the GNOME desktop environment

Glade: http://glade.gnome.org/

Answer (score -1):

Visual Ruby used with Glade are looking to be a nice combination.

http://visualruby.net/index.html

Comment: this is an opinion, not an answer, please include it as comment

Comment: The actual question is asking "Is there a rapid application development tool for GUI design using Ruby?" The answer to the question requires an opinion.